# Eror installing Perl Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA module

Tags: perl, cpan

I spent several hours but unable to install CPAN Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA module. It's required for Postfix's dkimproxy add-on.

What I do is to run the following command in the shell:

```
$ perl -MCPAN -e 'install Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA'
```

When I run this command, several lines are displayed and at the end, this is displayed:

```
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite Crypt::OpenSSL::Random 0 not found.
Writing Makefile for Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during [I/IR/IROBERTS/Crypt-OpenSSL-RSA-0.26.tar.gz] -----
    Crypt::OpenSSL::Random
Shall I follow them and prepend them to the queue
of modules we are processing right now? [yes]
```

Then I hit enter (yes) and tens of lines generated with error. At the end I get this:

```
...
...
RSA.xs:579: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘RSA_sign’
RSA.xs:579: error: ‘rsaData’ has no member named ‘hashMode’
RSA.xs:579: error: ‘rsaData’ has no member named ‘hashMode’
RSA.xs:579: error: ‘rsaData’ has no member named ‘rsa’
RSA.xs: In function ‘XS_Crypt__OpenSSL__RSA_verify’:
RSA.xs:605: error: ‘rsaData’ has no member named ‘rsa’
RSA.xs:610: error: ‘rsaData’ has no member named ‘hashMode’
RSA.xs:611: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘RSA_verify’
RSA.xs:611: error: ‘rsaData’ has no member named ‘hashMode’
RSA.xs:613: error: ‘rsaData’ has no member named ‘hashMode’
RSA.xs:616: error: ‘rsaData’ has no member named ‘rsa’
RSA.xs:619: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘ERR_peek_error’
RSA.xs: In function ‘boot_Crypt__OpenSSL__RSA’:
RSA.xs:214: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘ERR_load_crypto_strings’
make: *** [RSA.o] Error 1
  /usr/bin/make  -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

What am I doing wrong? Please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Just came across this problem myself on CentOS 5.4
I didn't have openssl-devel installed! So running:

`yum install openssl-devel`

fixed it for me

Or if you're on something debian-based:

`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 Note: The Ubuntu Spamassassin apt depo pkg did not install MAIL::DKIM, (and 2-3 others). Well, DKIM depends on Crypt::OpenSSL:: - and this was not installed via apt either. Crypt::SSL::* depends on the libssl-dev repo packge you mention. Package maintainers should have done this, though. Anyway, thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 2):

Odd, I have similar installed on Debian Squeeze, and this module always fails.

## perl Makefile.PL

Warning: prerequisite Crypt::OpenSSL::Random 0 not found.
Writing Makefile for Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA

..but I cannot find the exact package you refer to.
ii  libcrypt-openssl-bignum-perl     0.04-2                      Access OpenSSL multiprecision integer arithmetic libraries
ii  libcrypt-openssl-dsa-perl        0.13-4                      module which implements the DSA signature verification system
ii  libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl        0.25-1+b1                   Perl module providing basic RSA functionality
ii  libcrypt-openssl-x509-perl       1.4-1                       Perl extension to OpenSSL's X509 API

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a header somewhere.  Above what you posted in the output you should see a reference to a missing .h file.  Figure out what package provides that particular header and you're one step closer.  Lather...Rinse...Repeat, eventually it will compile :)

Comment: Looking more at your post you should probably install Crypt::OpenSSL::Random and try again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It seems that Crypt::OpenSSL::Random is causing the problem. Whenever I try to install this module with perl -MCPAN -e 'install Crypt::OpenSSL::Random' it generates errors I have pasted above.

Any ideas? I am unable to install dkimproxy for this reason :((((

Comment: Paste the full output of the installation of Crypt::OpenSSL::Random.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, that fixed my problem too on a Debian box.

Ran Aptitude, and then did a search for "openssl" and saw the lib-openssl package, and installed it.

Re-ran CPAN, did the install Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA and everything went smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem too for Ubuntu, but needed libengine-tpm-openssl.

Ran again:

$ sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA'

and it went ok.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem so many times it's not even funny. Always fixed with:

```
sudo apt-get install libnet-ssleay-perl
sudo apt-get install libcrypt-ssleay-perl
sudo apt-get install libio-socket-ssl-perl
```

You actually may only need 1, or in my case, sometimes you need all. Just depends on how proficient you are with your perl. Crypt, Openssl, Net::Twitter::Lite are a couple of things that have triggered the issue in the past.

Ron